# Webapplications redirect to subdirectory based on URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have two webapplications on my apache webserver.

/var/www/APP1
/var/www/APP2

Server = 1 IP Address.

Is it possible to connect multi URLS (www.test.com, www.secondtest.com) to my webapps.

www.test.com --> /var/www/APP1
www.secondtest.com --> /var/www/APP2

is it possible with htaccess? Or how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to do this. The better option would be to use multiple VirtualHosts (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html).

This allows you to map each domain directly to the location the files are located in.

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do. URL1 = file location /var/www/APP1, URL2 = filelocation /var/www/APP2